# Is it possible to edit tag of a file programatically using c++

Tags: c++, file, tags

I want to add/edit the tag of a file programatically using c++.But after seraching for almost 2 days I found nothing.Could you kindly help me whether we can add/edit the tag of a file using c++?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
I want to edit the OS level tag on file/directory.Eg:Each file has its own properties like Title,Subject,Categories and one among this is tags.I want to edit/add the property "Tags".
Thanks tony for suggestion.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: which tag do you mean? inside the source code? If so, you can use 'sed'

Comment: Goodness Ravi... how many conventions do you think there are for "tags" in/on files?  E.g. there are tags in media files, there are OS-level tags on files and directory - completely unrelated and specific to the file type or OS you're using.

Comment: You didn't tell us which OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed example about how to access the property values of a file:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186898

Here's a shorter example that shows how to write property values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380387(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't know about the property `Tags` (I haven't seen it anywhere), but as you see, it basically is possible to manipulate properties of NTFS files.